# I am trying to pull "tutors" that have not submitted a report for July. iSQLPLUS

Tags: sql, select

I am trying to see if this works:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (TutorReport.Month, 'MONTH') MONTH, TutorReport.MatchID, MatchHistory.MatchID, MatchHistory.Tutor.ID
FROM TutorReport, MatchID
WHERE TutorReport.MatchID=MatchHistory.MatchID
AND NOT (TutorReport.Month=‘JULY’);
```

Tables:

**TutorReport:** MatchID, Month, Hours, Lessons

**MatchHistory** MatchID, TutorID, Subject, Student ID, StartDate EndDate

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hint: Look into `where tutor_id not in (subquery)`

Answer (score 2):

You can join the tables using `LEFT JOIN`,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    MatchHistory a
        LEFT JOIN TutorReport b
            ON  a.MatchID = b.MatchID AND
                TO_CHAR(b.Month, 'Month') = 'JULY'
WHERE   b.MatchID IS NULL
```